# Error on eclipse updating

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error while adding new plugin in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13141956/error-while-adding-new-plugin-in-eclipse)

When i tried to instail this plugin http://fornwall.net/eclipsecoder/
I found this problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qjDN.png

So how can i solve this problem?

Comment: please can any one help me to solve this problem.